# How to configure app to use live coonect api in winRT metro app c#?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I want to configure my windows RT application in c# to use live connect API(As per   "**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826541.aspx**"). If i go to Windows Store Dashboard("**https://appdev.microsoft.com/StorePortals/en-us/account/signup/start**"), it ask me to register the app on store expecting more details form me with price i think and i don't want to do that as i just want to explore this topic for sample application.i have created package id before..but ti thinks i have lost that link from were i did this.so how to configure my sample application to use live connect API.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Store Dashboard is the right place, you'll just need to register a name and then you can to the configuration section for Live Services and Push Notifications.  You don't need to enter all of the other information until you're ready to publish your app.

[image]

Comment: hi can you please give me the link for this. because when i go to dashboard it goes to "https://appdev.microsoft.com/StorePortals/en-us/Account/Signup/SelectAccountType". which i don't want.i just want to create package id for my test application

Comment: to test the Live Services (and push notifications) you will need to create an application in the portal, which requires a developer license ($49)

Comment: ok. Did all the thing. still getting same exception that "The app is not configured correctly to use Live Connect services. To configure your app, please follow the instructions on http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=220871." any idea??